# Drupal node template for webform

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-webform

I'm trying to give my webform node a readable name to make it easier to find and edit.
I'm able to use the template I created called "webform-form-12.tpl.php" and theme that, but I want to use something like "node-webform-form-athlete-of-the-month_submit-your-athlete.tpl.php". The path I gave this webform is "athlete-of-the-month/submit-your-athlete". It's not working with any names I've tried. I'm using a node preprocess function to add template file names. I've tried these so far:
node-webform-athlete-of-the-month_submit-your-athlete.tpl.php
node-webform-form-athlete-of-the-month_submit-your-athlete.tpl.php
This one: "node-athlete-of-the-month_submit-your-athlete.tpl.php" uses the template but the form is not there.

Answer (score 1):

What version of webform? The latest Webform 2.x and 3.x should support the use of TPLs.

Comment: I just upgraded, I was using 2.x.
As I was creating a form, I thought I saw something about a template in the options, but now I don't see it anymore.

thanks